# Why Reducer required in a Hive Insert

Tags: hive, mapreduce, bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2

Question is related to working of MapReduce job when we fire a insert into statement from hive command line.
While inserting records into a hive table: As there is no aggregations involved while insert into the internal hive table, why reducer is also invoked. It should only a mapper job only.
What is the role of reducer here.

```
insert into table values (1,1);
```

```
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
INFO  : 2021-04-28 10:30:26,487 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2021-04-28 10:30:30,604 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.96 sec
INFO  : 2021-04-28 10:30:36,774 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 3.35 sec
INFO  : MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 350 msec
```

```
hive> set hive.merge.mapfiles;
hive.merge.mapfiles=true
hive> set hive.merge.mapredfiles;
hive.merge.mapredfiles=false
hive> set mapreduce.job.reduces;
mapreduce.job.reduces=-1
```

```
explain insert into test values (10,14);

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-7 depends on stages: Stage-1 , consists of Stage-4, Stage-3, Stage-5
  Stage-4
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-4, Stage-3, Stage-6
  Stage-2 depends on stages: Stage-0
  Stage-3
  Stage-5
  Stage-6 depends on stages: Stage-5

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: _dummy_table
            Row Limit Per Split: 1
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 10 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
            Select Operator
              expressions: array(const struct(10,14)) (type: array<struct<col1:int,col2:int>>)
              outputColumnNames: _col0
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 48 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
              UDTF Operator
                Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 48 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                function name: inline
                Select Operator
                  expressions: col1 (type: int), col2 (type: int)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                  Select Operator
                    expressions: _col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: int)
                    outputColumnNames: i, j
                    Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                    Group By Operator
                      aggregations: compute_stats(i, 'hll'), compute_stats(j, 'hll')
                      mode: hash
                      outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                      Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 848 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                      Reduce Output Operator
                        sort order: 
                        Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 848 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                        value expressions: _col0 (type: struct<columntype:string,min:bigint,max:bigint,countnulls:bigint,bitvector:binary>), _col1 (type: struct<columntype:string,min:bigint,max:bigint,countnulls:bigint,bitvector:binary>)
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          aggregations: compute_stats(VALUE._col0), compute_stats(VALUE._col1)
          mode: mergepartial
          outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
          Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 880 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
          File Output Operator
            compressed: false
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 880 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
            table:
                input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-7
    Conditional Operator

  Stage: Stage-4
    Move Operator
      files:
          hdfs directory: true
          destination:<path>
  Stage: Stage-0
    Move Operator
      tables:
          replace: false
          table:
              input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
              output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
              serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-2
    Stats Work
      Basic Stats Work:
      Column Stats Desc:
          Columns: i, j
          Column Types: int, int
          Table: db.test.test

  Stage: Stage-3
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            File Output Operator
              compressed: false
              table:
                  input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                  output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                  serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                  name: db.test

  Stage: Stage-5
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            File Output Operator
              compressed: false
              table:
                  input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                  output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                  serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                  name: db.test

  Stage: Stage-6
    Move Operator
      files:
          hdfs directory: true
          destination: <PATH>
          
Time taken: 5.123 seconds, Fetched: 121 row(s)
```

Comment: Please provide EXPLAIN output. Also check `hive.merge.mapfiles`, `hive.merge.mapredfiles` properties, also check `mapreduce.job.reduces`.

Comment: @leftjoin I have updated the explain plan. I just want to know why reducer is required in case of role.

Comment: @leftjoin also there is one more table. When I'm doing normal insert for that. For that its saying "there is no reducer operator". So no of reducer = 0.

Comment: I guess it can be statistics auto-gathering. But not sure what conditional operator exactly does... It can check stats exists and trigger statistics gathering job for final table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have statistics auto gathering enabled:

```
SET hive.stats.autogather=true;
```

And reducer is calculating statistics

```
Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          aggregations: **compute_stats**(VALUE._col0), compute_stats(VALUE._col1)
          mode: mergepartial
```

Comment: yes : hive.stats.autogather=true.
But it should call that stats for other table also while doing insert. Right . For other its not doing that.

Comment: For other table: "Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator"

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2021-04-29 11:05:03,750 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2021-04-29 11:05:08,043 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.76 sec

Comment: @shobhit Yes. that is strange. Is it some difference in tables DDL? Both tables contained some data before insert or were empty?... though hive.merge.mapredfiles=false and it should not merge with existing files in both cases... interesting

Comment: @shobhit Is it any difference in tables DDL?

Comment: yes I can see one difference : ------------
COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   {\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}  -- this present in one table. Table Parameters: 
im checking using describe formatted.

Comment: @shobhit That property reflects current stats state: accurate or not. After insert statement it should became true for the table in question, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231750/discussion-between-shobhit-and-leftjoin).